# No difference between baseTime and trafficTime for a long period of time

Tags: routes, here-api, here-traffic

I have a set of latitudes-longitudes in Fairfax,VA and I am interested in getting time taken to travel between them across almost whole 2019, every hour.

I observe that the values in baseTime and trafficTime are the same for every combination of lat-long I have and every hour of the year.

I've been using this [API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/example-time-aware-route.html) to query historical data.

What might be the reason behind this?
Was the traffic data, which may impact the trafficTime, not collected for this location for this period? Did anyone have a similar experience and found anything?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding documentation on https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-route.html

**the historical traffic is limited to one year**

> departure: Time when travel is expected to start. Traffic speed and
> incidents are taken into account when calculating the route, where
> applicable (note that in case of a past departure time ***the historical
> traffic is limited to one year***). You can use now to specify the
> current time. Specify either departure or arrival, not both. Type:
> xs:dateTime.

Interesting but currently is still available from 2020-01-01.